# Mongodb atlas not connectin

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this issue with mongodb atlas. I can connect to it for awhile but then it throws an error(5 minutes or so). Here is what the terminal is sending me.,

{ Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.medianode-
.mongodb.net

```
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:199:19)

 errno: 'ETIMEOUT',

 code: 'ETIMEOUT',

  syscall: 'querySrv',

 hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.medianode-mgglv.mongodb.net' }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the network from which you are connecting to the MongoDB server is not white-listed. Make sure your IP is added to "Network access" section under Security. To provide access for everyone, you can add 0.0.0.0/0 otherwise just add the specific IP.

[image: Network access, MongoDB]